# What is the recommended way of adding selection behavior to an Ember.js CollectionView?

Tags: ember.js

I need basically a Select view, but I would like something a bit more visually appealing.  My hunch is that I can use a CollectionView to do this, but that I'll have to implement selection of elements within the collection myself.  Is this a common practice?  Is there a recommended way to do this?  Are there any good examples?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm reading this correctly you just want something that's prettier than your basic select list.  I don't know your constraints, but I really like the [bootstrap dropdowns](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) for these types of things

Easy: Try and style your `<select>`'s to your liking

```
{{view Ember.Select 
    contentBinding="App.content" 
    optionLabelBinding="content.text"
    optionValueBinding="content.value"
    selectionBinding="App.selection"
    prompt="Choose ...."}}
```

If you go with Bootstrap, something like this should work

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
  {{#each App.content}}
      {{#view App.SelectView contentBinding="this"}}{{label}}{{/view}}
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
App.SelectView = Em.View.extend({
   tagName: 'li',
   click:function(){
      App.set('selected', this.get('content'));
      // then hide the dropdown
   }
});
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to build some miller columns, so a select isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

This link was recommended to me on #emberjs on Freenode:

https://gist.github.com/1626943

It extends CollectionView to allow selecting items.